# Get the title atribute from UL list and check if a title already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this UL:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-group-item" title="Test1">Test1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" title="Test2">Test2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" title="Test3">Test3</li>
</ul>
```

I have a string with new `<li>` to insert but I need to check if this new title already exists to prevent duplicated.

How to do this with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: kindly include the things you have tried. js or something

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/0mtwgz8p/).

```
var newTitle = 'Test1';
if ( $('[title="' + newTitle  + '"]').length === 0 ) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="list-group-item" title="' + newTitle +'">' + newTitle + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: Glad I helped! Could you then accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
<button id="my-button">Add New Title</button>
```

You want to create a new array, where you will store all of our title attributes. We will query a list of all elements in our DOM with the use of the wildcard selector `*`. With this, we can iterate over all DOM elements, and get their titles, which will be stored in our attributes array.

To save space, we will first check if each element has a title attribute. Only if it does, will we append the element to our array.

```
var attributes = [];

var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    if (allElements[i].getAttribute("title")) {
        attributes.push(allElements[i].getAttribute("title"));
    }
}
```

Next, we need to store references to our button for creating new list items, and for our list ourselves.

```
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
var list = document.getElementById("my-list");
```

We will listen for the click event and prompt the user for input. After that, we will use the `indexOf` property to see if the title already exists. If it doesn't we can create a new element and append it to our list. If not, we will simply return false.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var title = prompt("Enter a title");
    if (attributes.indexOf(title) === -1) {
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        var listTitle = document.createTextNode(title);
        listItem.setAttribute("title", title);
        listItem.appendChild(listTitle);
        list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
   else {
       return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop trought the titles with the `$.each` function.

```js
function checkTitle(newTitle){
    var listGroup = $("#list-group li");
    $.each(listGroup, function(i, s){
        var title = $(s).attr("title");

        if(newTitle.toLowerCase() === title.toLowerCase()){
            $(".message").html("Title allready exist!")
            return false;
        } else {
         $(".message").html("Title does not exist!")
        }
    })
}
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    var newTitle = $("#new-title").val();
    checkTitle(newTitle)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" title="Test1">Test1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" title="Test2">Test2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" title="Test3">Test3</li>
</ul>
<form id="form-new-title">
    <input type="text" id="new-title">
    <button id="submit">
        Send
    </button>
</form>

<div class="message">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, without more code or context it's not very specific but it should be easy to adapt to your situation.

```js
var titles = ['i1','i2','i4'];

$('ul li').each(function(){
  
  var tmpTitle = $(this).attr('title');
  
  if(titles.indexOf(tmpTitle) > -1) {
    // already exists
  } else {
    // doesn't exist
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li title="i1">item 1</li>
  <li title="i2">item 2</li>
  <li title="i3">item 3</li>
  <li title="i4">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to find values in a node list.  (non-jquery)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

<ul id = "item_list">
        <li class="list-group-item" title="Test1">Test1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item" title="Test2">Test2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item" title="Test3">Test3</li>
</ul>

    <p>
        Add Title:  <input type = "text" id = "item_entry"><button onclick="addItem(itemEntry.value)">Add It !</button>
    <p id = "entry_log"></p>

    </body>
    <script>

    var entryLog = document.getElementById('entry_log');
    var itemList = document.getElementById('item_list');
    var itemEntry = document.getElementById('item_entry');

            function addItem(item) {
                if ( !titleExists (item) ) {
                    var newItem = document.createElement('LI');
                    newItem.title = item;
                    newItem.className = 'list-group-item';

                    var itemText = document.createTextNode(item);
                    newItem.appendChild(itemText);

                    itemList.appendChild(newItem);

                    entryLog.style.color = 'green';
                    entryLog.innerHTML = 'New Item: ' + item + ' added successfully.';
                } else {
                        entryLog.style.color = 'red';
                        entryLog.innerHTML = item + ' already exists';
                    }

            }


            function titleExists (title) {
                var listItems = itemList.getElementsByTagName('LI');
                var titleCheck = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
                        if ( title == listItems[i].getAttribute('title') ) {
                            titleCheck = true;
                        }
                    }
                return titleCheck;
            }

    </script>
    </html>
```

Node lists are handy but you can't use array functions like indexOf() on them.  You just gotta round up all the suspects and beat it out of them individually.

Any js library will have a shorter version, but the recursion still has to go on somewhere, even though you don't see it.